# Extracting the AudioBuffer of an <audio> element

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audio-processing

Is there a way to extract the AudioBuffer of an  element for analysis? I want to avoid dealing with cross-origin issues that arise when using an XMLHttpRequest, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because an  element doesn't necessarily have a backing AudioBuffer (it may be streaming an hour-long podcast, for example - you don't want a gigabyte-order AudioBuffer).

It would be possible to RECORD (in realtime, unfortunately, not faster) the output of an  element - createmediaelementsource() it and hook it up to code like RecordJS.

Comment: Is it possible somehow by setting the preload attribute to true?

Comment: Still no.  You just don't get to drill into the <audio> innards like that.  Preload just tells the (desktop-only, IIRC) browser to go ahead and start loading prior to clicking play.